# NativeActivity does not display on screen

Tags: java, android

On my Android device (with JellyBean 4.1.2) there's a bug:

When I start a specific NativeActivity (libretroarch-activity to load a game from my app), the emulator activity is shown as if it is "behind" my application layout, I can only see it if I set the app theme to `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.FullScreen` , and as you can see the black areas become transparent too! [image: Semi-Transparent Bug]

When I set the theme to `Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.FullScreen` and I launch the game, I instead see a full black screen, but if I rotate the screen I can see the game for some istants, then when screen orientation process ends, screen turns black again. Another thing that I've noticed is that if I overlay my view with some non-transparent element, like volume adjust or power off dialog, for some seconds after this disappears, I see for some istants the game screen only inside the limited area where there was the element. Here's a [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uj3XbSEoes) that shows the screen orientation weird behavior (as you can see it behaves the same even in stock app, can it be AOSP bug?), and [here is a video](http://youtu.be/PPBMQBAnkhM) of the bug that allows game view only if there's an overlay dialog.

As a temporary fix would it be possible to overlay my activity with some empty layout set at minimum opacity, so that the game screen can be seen? Otherwise is it a android known issue that can be fixed or is it related to retroarch?

Comment: which version of android do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a chat with the RetroArch Authors it came out that it's a bug in their libraries that will be fixed in the new version that will come out soon.